# What is a harmonic complex function?

Tags: complex-analysis, self-learning, harmonic-functions, partial-derivative

So, as far as I have learned, a complex function $f(u)$ is considered harmonic if and only if it satisfies the undermentioned equation:
$$
\frac{\partial ^2 u}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial ^2 u}{\partial y^2} = 0
$$
for any given complex number $x+iy$.

Is that right ?

Comment: @GitGud Yes, I know how to calculate second order derivatives. You calculate the derivative of the derivative. Right ? :)

Comment: Actually what do you mean with $f(u)$?

Comment: @GitGud a complex function ??

Comment: Check Michael's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that a real function $u(x,y)$ is harmonic if it obeys that equation.  If it does, then there is another real function $v(x,y)$ that is also harmonic, and there is a complex function $f(x+iy)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$ which is differentiable.  By that, I mean, you can write $f(x+iy)=g(x+iy,x-iy)=g(z,\overline{z})$, and $\partial g/\partial\overline{z}=0$

Comment: You are right: a real function u(x,y) is harmonic if it solves the Laplace equation. Also, a complex-function function is harmonic if it solves the Laplace equation. In other words,  the real and the imaginary part of a complex harmonic function are real- valued harmonic functions, which **need not** satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations. [Sources](https://www.google.com/search?q="complex+harmonic+function"&source=lnms&tbm=bks).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the harmonic functions are those satisying the Laplace equation $\Delta u=0$, where $\Delta\equiv\partial_x^2+\partial_y^2$ is the Laplace operator. Usually one assumes them to be of class $C^2$ (defined on some open subset of the complex plane, say, and taking real values; of course one can consider more general situations), but since any harmonic function admits (locally, which is enough of course) a harmonic conjugate, they are automatically of class $C^\infty$.

Comment: So calculate the first order partial derivative, then partial derivative of the first order PD. Add the two equations (2nd order PD wrt x and wrt y). If they equate to zero then the function is harmonic

Comment: @LittleChild Yes. A complex-valued functions is called harmonic if both real and imaginary parts are harmonic. Just as a vector-valued function is harmonic if each component is harmonic. You check this condition separately for each component. ... By the way, you made a mistake accepting the other answer. What Michael wrote is correct, but is not an answer to your question.